# document.forms.length inside function returns 0, outside of function works right

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Can anyone explain to me why the following code doesn't work within a function but outside of a function it works perfectly?

```
function calculate_document_forms_length(){
    document.forms.length;
}
```

Running it from the console returns "undefined", but when I just run document.forms.length from the console itself returns the number of forms on the page. I've tried to understand why this isn't working but I'm unable to find a reason for it. It happens in firefox, and also chrome. I see no reason why that shouldn't work.

Edit to clarify a few things.

It's ran from the console after the page is done loading. And the following returns the proper value.

```
document.forms.length;
```

Thus I don't know why it's acting this way.

OK here's the exact source of the test HTML page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test page 01</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="test1" />
    </form>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="tes2" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see no frames, nothing but plain HTML and forms within the  tag.

Comment: Are you calling your function before your HTML has been rendered?

Comment: It's ran from the console. After the page is done running. I wait till the page is done, and then I write it. And I doubt it'd make a difference if I put it in a function or not since the document.forms.length works just fine outside of a function.

Comment: None, as stated above, and reedited, the full code is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have there doesn't return anything (i.e. when you run it, it "returns" `undefined`). Try this instead:

```
function() {
    return document.forms.length;
}
```

Also, if you run just that in the console, you'll still get `undefined`, because you're still not *calling* the function. You're just creating it, but it's still not being executed.

If you want to run it in the console, you can write

```
(function() {
    return document.forms.length;
}());
```

Lastly, if you just write `document.forms.length` in the console, the console will show you the value, because `length` is a variable. So that's why that seemed to work.

Comment: My original one did a console.log, and it's in a different function that still doesn't want to do it. And returning won't really help an undefined value.

Comment: @133794m3r: Your original one? If you wrote `function(){console.log(document.forms.length);}` in the console, you're still just creating a function, not executing it. But if you write `(function(){console.log(document.forms.length);}())` it'll create _and_ execute the function, and it'll log the length in the console. I can guarantee you it works, since I just tried it myself

Comment: Then why is the following one not working. I originally thought it was something to do with the function itself. I have a function which is calling this and it always say the following variable "len" is 0.  var len=document.forms.length; And it is ran from a function in and of itself. I originally wrote this thinking that the "inside a function" thing was the problem. Now I don't knwo if I should close this one and open a new one with that one's full code or just leave this be forever here.

Comment: @133794m3r: If it says `0` then it's not saying `undefined` - big difference. My guess is you're calling the function before the page has finished loading - in that case the number of forms will indeed be zero. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/QrB4G/

Comment: that's likely it. I forgot to wait for dom readiness, since I'm used to just using jquery. And I was writing up a little thing and just doing it in pure javascript to see how well I still remembered this weird obscure language. I'll mark yours as the answer since I seem to have forgotten it.

Comment: @133794m3r: Thanks. And JS isn't that weird - it's the DOM and browsers that are weird ;) -- And it's always good to do some pure JS. No library can beat having a solid understanding the underlying language.

Comment: The language itself is weird. I hate it, if it wasn't require to do front end web developemnt. I'd not use it at all. Camel cased, everythings in an object or a method of an object, utter crap. I wish it was less like java and more like c. I'm completely against all forms of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the why but if you return it, it works:

```
function aa(){
    return document.forms.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code `document.forms.length;` runs before the whole page is rendered.

To fix this:

1. Add a defer attribute to your script element
   OR
2. Move your script tag towards the end of your html, immediately above the body end tag.